# Why doesn't C++ have the ~= and != operators?

Tags: c++

This is pretty much as described in the title:

Why doesn't C++ have the ~= and != operators?

They would occasionally be useful, particularly when exploring overloading possibilities.

The alternative `a = ~a` and `a = !a` formulations are unnecessarily verbose.

Comment: I take it you mean a binary `!=` as there is a [logical `!=`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison)

Comment: C++ already has `!=`, but I don't think it means what you think it means.

Comment: How would you spell `a = ~a` if there would be a `=~` operator?

Comment: @SergeyA. The operator would be `~=`, which is not ambiguous.

Comment: `~=` makes sense, and so would `^=`. They just weren't added in. Reason being "just cuz".

Comment: @MadPhysicist, question still stands. What I want to see is how this hypothetical operator provides for shorter code.

Comment: @MadPhysicist ^= exists - see http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators.htm or [Wikipedia Operators in C and C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B)

Comment: Personally I think -3 is a bit harsh on this new user. I can't find a duplicate and this question is well presented.

Comment: How is `a ~= a` less verbose than `a = ~a`? Can you clarify your proposed syntax?

Comment: @SergeyA. Fair enough. As Bathsheba's answer correctly points out, doing this for unary operators is pointless since it just rearranges characters without compressing anything.

Comment: This question is has a bad premise and even worse arguments.

Comment: Do consider voting to reopen, if anything to allow a better answer than mine to emerge.

Comment: @tuple_cat I don't think that's what Chump is asking for. The analogous form would be `~=a` as shorthand for `a = ~a`. And to better demonstrate the reduction of verbosity: `~=long_variable_name_here` versus `long_variable_name_here = ~long_variable_name_here`

Comment: @user2079303 This is possible, but we just do not know without Chump telling us. To me the question seems to assume the ~= should be present analogous to += or ^=, but the analogy is in fact not there.

Comment: @Suma yeah, the question itself would benefit from being more *verbose*.

Comment: Is there _any_ language that has `~=` or `!=`?

Comment: This belongs on https://meta.stackoverflow.com really.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Taking `@` as a "generic" operator, something like

```
a @= b
```

is shorthand for

```
a = a @ b
```

So you can see that the `@=` form applies to *binary* operators where the corresponding `@` takes 2 operands.

But `!` and `~` are *unary* operators. So `!=` and `~=` would be a departure from this. `@` when denoting *unary* operators equivalates `@=` and `=@` which is an unnecessary superfluity. Your assertion of verboseness is fallacious.

Comment: Why not define `$` as a generic unary operator and allow `a $= a` to be the same as `a = $a`? I agree that it's pointless and saves nothing, but it can be done.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Because that isn't any more compact, just rearranged.

Comment: @MadPhysicist how would you distinguish between `a != a` unary and `a != a` binary ?

Comment: @MadPhysicist, What's the point? All you're doing is swapping two characters. Looking at `a $= a`, I would expect `a` to be evaluated twice, so there's no benefit there, either.

Comment: @chris et al. As I mentioned in my comment, I realize the pointlesness of the definition. All I am saying is that it is possible. Shouldn't be done, but possible.

Comment: @tobi303 if the unary operators had the suggested alternative syntax, then there wouldn't and couldn't be both binary `!=` and unary `!`. They would be "distinguished" by giving one of them another symbol.

Comment: @user2079303 it was a rhetorical question of course it could be done somehow but I think we all agree that there is no real need of compound unary operators...

Comment: Also, if `a @= a would also be the shorthand for _unary_ @, we have a problem with `+=` and `-=` because they're both unary as well as binary. (Technically, so is *, but unary * is the pointer/iterator dereference)

Comment: It would also be rather pointless as `@=` would be equivalent to `=@`. The OPs assertion of verbosity is a red herring.